# Как правильно споцизионировать элементы grid?

Tags: html, css, grid

Данные картинки не могу правильно расположить на странице, помогите пожалуйста.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.grid__list {
  display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
   grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 30px;
 row-gap: 30px;
}
.item_1 {
  width: 255px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
}
.item_2 {
  width: 255px;
  height: 235px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
}
.item_3 {
 width: 255px;
  height: 235px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 30px 0px; 
}
.item_4 {
  width: 540px;
  height: 235px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  
}
.item_5 {
  width: 255px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid__list">
   <div class="grid__item item_1"></div>
   <div class="grid__item item_2"></div>
   <div class="grid__item item_3"></div>
   <div class="grid__item item_4"></div>
   <div class="grid__item item_5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какая часть не получается? Прочитайте как расположить элементы в `grid` с помощью [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).

Comment: я расположил элементы в 5 фракций, они как бы встали в одну линию, но картинку с текстом я не знаю как перенести вниз, она же тоже получается в линию идет

Comment: А где вы указали что они не должны встать в линию? По умолчанию, да, в линию встают.

Comment: Для картинки с текстом подсказка: `grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 4;`. Остальное дополните сами.

Comment: я почитал про grid-column-start и end, грид ареа это сокращенное свойство вроде от всех этих конструкций, не пойму правда откуда такой отступ между картинкой с текстом и двумя верхними картинками)

Comment: Отступ с помощью [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/gap) задают

Comment: это я знаю, изменил немного код, в чем моя ошибка не подскажете?

Comment: Для начала вы определили решетку 5 на 2. Надо 4 на 2. Потом вы задали позицию только для одного элемента. Задайте для остальных.

Comment: я там потыкал потыкал, человек снизу ответик скинул, у меня почему-то через grid-area не сработало, а через grid-row grid-column сработало с идентичными значениями ._. Спасибо вам за помощь, я немного хоть с этими гридами начал разбираться с вашей помощью)

Comment: [Пожалуйста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1498000/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-grid#comment2686179_1498000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.grid__list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:30px;
}

.item_1 {
  width: 255px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
  grid-area: 1/1/3/2;
  /*grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;*/
}

.item_2 {
  width: 255px;
  height: 235px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
  grid-area: 1/2/2/3;
  /*grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 2/3;*/
}

.item_3 {
  width: 255px;
  height: 235px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
  grid-area: 1/3/2/4;
  /*grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 3/4;*/
}

.item_4 {
  width: 540px;
  height: 235px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
  grid-area: 2/2/-1/4;
  /*grid-row: 2/-1;
  grid-column: 2/4;*/
}

.item_5 {
  width: 255px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 30px 0px;
  grid-area: 1/4/-1/-1;
  /*grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 4/-1;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid__list">
    <div class="grid__item item_1"></div>
    <div class="grid__item item_2"></div>
    <div class="grid__item item_3"></div>
    <div class="grid__item item_4"></div>
    <div class="grid__item item_5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало, я подставил такие же значения в grid-area, но оно почему-то начало коверкаться как-то, а через grid-column grid-row всё заработало, свойства в грид-ареа я точно правильно ставил, не знаю в чем прикол, но спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @100.1 Для более глубокого понимания переписал код на `grid-area`